# how to execute selenium in aws lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, aws-lambda

We used a lot of Google search and stackoverflow.

However, I didn't know how to operate selenium on AWS Lambda.

`First of all, what I've tried.`

**0. Using AWS toolkit, SAM Application Success**

**1. The selenium module has been compressed.**

**2. I uploaded selenium zip file by adding layer to lambda function.**

**3. An error occurred even though it was executed.**

`Selenium code to operate on awslambda`

```
import json,os
from selenium import webdriver


def get_driver():
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1280x1696')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--v=99')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--single-process')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--data-path=/tmp/data-path')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--homedir=/tmp')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir')
    chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36')
    chrome_options.binary_location = os.getcwd() + "/bin/headless-chromium"
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    return driver
    
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    driver = get_driver()
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
    page_data = driver.page_source
    driver.close ()
    return page_data
```

**but error message occured**

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home\n",
  "errorType": "WebDriverException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/app.py\", line 29, in lambda_handler\n    driver = get_driver()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/app.py\", line 24, in get_driver\n    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py\", line 68, in __init__\n    self.service.start()\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py\", line 81, in start\n    raise WebDriverException(\n"
  ]
}
```

Please help me with the problem.

I've been trying so hard to solve this problem for seven days.

Of course, I read the aws document, but there was no helpful data for selenium operation.

**update post**
[image]

**AWS Lambda Dashboard**
[image]

**update post  @RichEdwards**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, path='/opt/python/bin/chromedriver')
```

[image]

> how to execute selenium in aws lambda ?

Comment: The error suggests you don't have chromedriver.exe available. You specify the path when creating your object: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, path='path/to/chromedriver.exe')`   -  (binary_location isn't the chromedriver location)

Comment: @RichEdwards  error message occured :   `"errorMessage": "name 'chrome_options' is not defined"` , update post view please

Comment: Here is a post that explains how to deploy a lambda with selenium using docker in case it helps - https://medium.com/@karthiks3000/aws-serverless-architecture-with-sam-part-4-688873f5742

Answer (score 1):

By checking [selenium python source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py#L36). It looks, the `path` parameter does not exist, maybe `executable_path` is what you want.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='/opt/python/bin/chromedriver')
```